# stop web integration to unity in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: unity, webapps

I don't want webapps integration in Ubuntu, so is there any way I can  stop Webapps integration to Unity in Ubuntu 13.10 OS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Unity tweak tool and then open it.. From there at Unity tab choose webapps . from there you can disable and enable it as you want.

[image]

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or disable the "Unity Desktop Integration" Addon in the Addon-Manager at "extras" if you're using Firefox. Worked fine with me.

Comment: an image may give more clarity. thanks for posting